# getopt_long treat option name as argument

Tags: c++, c, linux, getopt, getopt-long

I was using getopt_long read command line options. code:

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ch;
    struct option longopts[] = {
        {"password", required_argument, NULL, 'p'},
        {"viewonly", no_argument, NULL, 'v'},
        {"help", no_argument, NULL, 'h'},
        {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
    };
    while ((ch = getopt_long(argc, argv, "p:vh", longopts, NULL)) != -1) {
        switch (ch) {
        case 'p':
            printf("optarg: %x %s\n", optarg, optarg);
            break;
        case 'v':
            printf("viewonly is set\n");
            break;
        case 'h':
        case '?':
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I using this command line option: `./a.out --password --viewonly`, It's supposed to print error message that `--password` is missing argument, but `getopt_long` never return '?', but treat `--viewonly` as the `optarg` of `--password`. and the output is:

```
optarg: 24992bc4 --viewonly
```

I think it's strange, and what should I do to prevent getopt_long treat option name as argument?

Comment: You can't. Instead you have to detect the problem later in the code, like when checking the password and then tell the user that the user provided the wrong password.

Comment: but it also hide `viewonly` option from being read. Can it be correct manually?

Comment: If the user provides the wrong password, will you even get far enough in the program to use the `viewonly` option? The user passing the wrong password (or it's "missing" like in your case) it should be a pretty fatal error, which means that the user will re-run your program with the (hopefully correct) password, and the issue is kind of moot. Your problem is only a problem in a small test program like the one provided here.

Comment: If you're using C++, try Boost Program Options instead.

Comment: it's right here. but I think there are some other conditions to be consider. and why getopt_long didn't detect if the optarg is start with '-' or '--' and return '?' ?

Comment: Two things to consider: First of all `getopt_long` is not a standard function anywhere, it's a GNU libc extension. Secondly: There is nowhere specified that it *must* check for options when expecting a non-option argument. It simply sees that you have the `password` option, it requires an argument, and provides you with that argument, no matter what that argument is.

Comment: I understand. Looks like I must check the `optarg` myself, and I already tested that `getopt` has the same problem.

Comment: Just be careful, because who says that the user may not have e.g. `--viewonly` (or any other option you might have) as password?

Comment: That's right, I will ignore this issue at this moment, and try to avoid option required argument.

Answer (score 0):

I would have some error checking in my switch statement (maybe check that a password cannot start with '--')